# Admob show rate gone down dramatically after migrating from native Android to Expo React Native

Tags: android, react-native, expo, admob

I have an app that has a few small and medium sized banner ads. The app used to be written in native Android (java) code, and it had a near 100% match rate and the show rate was around 80-90%. A few months ago, I switched to a React Native implementation. The match rate is still the same, but the show rate has gone down a lot and is now around 50%.

I have no idea why this is happening. The number of ad requests is about the same, and there's no obvious load time difference when I'm testing on my device (both prod and dev versions). Additionally, The React Native version is only available on Android, so there aren't any iOS or web versions altering the metrics.

Here are some relevant NPM packages and their versions. I'm using Expo and their AdMob package to display ads:

- react@17.0.1
- react-native@0.64.3
- expo@43.0.4
- expo-ads-admob@11.0.3

Here's how I'm using the `AdMobBanner` component, it's pretty standard:

```
<AdMobBanner
  bannerSize="mediumRectangle"
  adUnitID={adUnitID}
  onDidFailToReceiveAdWithError={handleAdError}
  style={{ alignSelf: "center" }}
/>
```

The only complication I could think of is that the ad is being rendered in an animated flatlist (`Animated.FlatList`). The list slides into the screen as soon as the user lands on the page, and the ad renders pretty quickly after the animation. The Android version also had this animation, so I don't think that's the cause.

Comment: Hi @Ninjaman494, where you able to figure out the issue? I am facing the same issue here.

Comment: facing the same issue